# Switch audio between headphone and speaker

Tags: audio, speakers, headphones

I have one audio output in my pc, I have attached an audio splitter and attached my headphone and speaker ports to that. now when I play audio both of my headphone and speaker play the audio. because the port to the pc is the same I can't set a default and disable the other audio player to switch between them. I wanted to ask if there is anyway to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A USB to audio jack would do the trick. 
You can pick them up for around $10usd off the Internet. 
It basically lets Windows detect a new  generic sound device plugged in via USB, and then you connect whatever you like to the adapter.

You could have the speakers via the pc audio out, and the headphones off the adapter.

Other than that, there is no other way I can think of. This is a purely hardware limit on your pc.